# Spring WebClient filter Null from Json Request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am using Spring WebClient Api to make a rest api call.

I have an entity object--**JobInfo** which acts as my POST Request pay-load.

The below Rest API fails because certain attributes of **JobInfo** are null.

```
private BatchInfo createBulkUploadJob(JobInfo jobInfo) {
        return webClient.post()
                .uri(URL.concat("/services/data/v47.0/jobs/ingest/"))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header("Authorization", "OAuth " + TOKEN)
                .bodyValue(jobInfo)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(BatchInfo.class)
                .block();
    }
```

I need to filter out the Null attributes from sending it across the rest call.

I understand this can be easily achieved by including below annotation on JobInfo class.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
```

But **JobInfo** is coming from a third party Jar, so I cannot touch this class.

Is there a way I can configure this in webClient to filter this out or any other option ?

Comment: For third party jars with jacksons you should use a mixin to apply the configuration to the third party class. https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/JacksonMixInAnnotations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this:

```
private BatchInfo createBulkUploadJob(JobInfo jobInfo) {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        ExchangeStrategies strategies = ExchangeStrategies
                .builder()
                .codecs(clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer -> {
                    clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonEncoder(new Jackson2JsonEncoder(objectMapper, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
                    clientDefaultCodecsConfigurer.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(objectMapper, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

                }).build();

        WebClient webClient = WebClient.builder().exchangeStrategies(strategies).build();
        return webClient.post()
                .uri(URL.concat("/services/data/v47.0/jobs/ingest/"))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header("Authorization", "OAuth " + TOKEN)
                .bodyValue(jobInfo)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(BatchInfo.class)
                .block();
    }
```

Comment: Hello, doing it this way replace the ObjectMapper auto-configured by Spring. So it breaks, for instance, the serialization and deserialization of dates. 
Sorry for this negative comment: I'd like to provide a working solution but I'm still looking for how to avoid things like "`{"propName":null}` in the generated json... :(

Comment: could you elaborate your problem? there is multiple way to avoid null exclusion in serialization.

Comment: Thanks for your question. 
Actually "my" issue is not really with the _null exclusion in serialization_. It's in the global way to configure Spring Boot here. What you propose forces the creation of a specific Object Mapper, and thus it blocks all other Spring configuration stuff coming from the `application.properties` file, to configure the default object mapper (like date format...).
In most cases, it would be possible to add all this configuration in this specific ObjectMapper, But it's not in my case for other reasons.